# Subtracting two columns in pandas with lists to create a cummalative column

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe consists of set x which is a universal set and subset column contains of some subsets. I want to choose the subsets with the highest ratios until I covered the full set x.

Uncovered = setx - subset

This is how my dataframe look like in pandas :

```
   ratio                  set x        subset        uncovered
2   2.00  [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 0, 7]  [8, 3, 6, 1]        [0, 9, 7]
0   1.50  [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 0, 7]     [1, 3, 6]     [0, 8, 9, 7]
1   1.00  [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 0, 7]        [9, 0]  [8, 1, 3, 6, 7]
3   0.75  [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 0, 7]     [1, 3, 7]     [0, 8, 6, 9]
```

I want to create another column with the subtraction of set x with cumulative of uncovered column until i get a empty list.

I tried the below code

```
p['tt']=list(p['set x']-p['subset'])
```

Error Message :

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   /Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py
>   in na_op(x, y)
>       581             result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y,
>   --> 582                                           raise_on_error=True, **eval_kwargs)
>       583         except TypeError:
>
> /Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/computation/expressions.py
>   in evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error, use_numexpr,
>   **eval_kwargs)
>       208         return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error=raise_on_error,
>   --> 209                          **eval_kwargs)
>       210     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error=raise_on_error)
>
> /Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/computation/expressions.py
>   in _evaluate_numexpr(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error, truediv,
>   reversed, **eval_kwargs)
>       119     if result is None:
>   --> 120         result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error)
>       121
>
> /Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/computation/expressions.py
>   in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error, **eval_kwargs)
>        61         _store_test_result(False)
>   ---> 62     return op(a, b)
>        63
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 p['tt']=list(p['set x']-p['subset'])
>
> /Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py
>   in wrapper(left, right, name, na_op)
>       639                     rvalues = algos.take_1d(rvalues, ridx)
>       640 
>   --> 641             arr = na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
>       642 
>       643             return left._constructor(wrap_results(arr), index=index,
>
> /Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py
>   in na_op(x, y)
>       586                 result = np.empty(x.size, dtype=dtype)
>       587                 mask = notnull(x) & notnull(y)
>   --> 588                 result[mask] = op(x[mask], _values_from_object(y[mask]))
>       589             elif isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
>       590                 result = np.empty(len(x), dtype=x.dtype)
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Comment: Is your code not working? Have you tried it in pandas?

Comment: Its not working. Yes, I tried in pandas

Comment: Is the above your pandas code? What is not working?

Comment: Pls see my edited post

Comment: You are essentially doing list operations, not set operations. `-` is not defined for lists. I don't know if pandas stores sets, but you can always cast a list into a set. This might work `p['tt']=list(set(p['set x'])-set(p['subset']))`

Comment: @TammoHeeren its giving me the following error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: You are right. `p['set x']` will return the entire column. You can write a function to apply to each row instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
import pandas as pd

#    ratio                  set x        subset        uncovered
# 2   2.00  [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 0, 7]  [8, 3, 6, 1]        [0, 9, 7]
# 0   1.50  [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 0, 7]     [1, 3, 6]     [0, 8, 9, 7]
# 1   1.00  [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 0, 7]        [9, 0]  [8, 1, 3, 6, 7]
# 3   0.75  [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 0, 7]     [1, 3, 7]     [0, 8, 6, 9]

p = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {'set x': [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 0, 7], 'subset': [1, 3, 6]},
        {'set x': [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 0, 7], 'subset': [9, 0]},
        {'set x': [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 0, 7], 'subset': [8, 3, 6, 1]},
        {'set x': [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 0, 7], 'subset': [1, 3, 7]},
    ])


def set_operation(x):
    return list(set(x['set x']) - set(x['subset']))

p['tt'] = p.apply(set_operation, axis=1)
```

Result is:

```
                   set x        subset               tt
0  [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 0, 7]     [1, 3, 6]     [0, 8, 9, 7]
1  [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 0, 7]        [9, 0]  [8, 1, 3, 6, 7]
2  [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 0, 7]  [8, 3, 6, 1]        [0, 9, 7]
3  [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 0, 7]     [1, 3, 7]     [0, 8, 9, 6]
```